# UITableViewCell height not getting updated on scroll (cell reuse issue)

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, ios8, autolayout

I have variable cell height working with auto-layout (ios8) as per this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18746929/using-auto-layout-in-uitableview-for-dynamic-cell-layouts-variable-row-heights?rq=1).

Cell heights are correct when table is loaded.  But if I scroll the table cell height is not correct for some cells.  Seems cell is being reused without height being readjusted.

I have one custom view in the cell that determines the height of the cell.  I have overridden instrinsicContentSize for that view.

It seems instrinsicContentSize is not called on cell reuse.
I have tried setNeedsLayout, setNeedsDisplay etc to get cell height to be updated on resuse but no luck.

Answer (score 1):

Needed to call invalidateIntrinsicContentSize for the custom view when configuring cell.